# Which register holds the final arithmetic and logic results?

Tags: cpu, register, alu

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing))  says

> an accumulator is a register in which **intermediate** arithmetic and
>   logic results are stored.

So which register holds the **final** result?

Comment: Depends on the cpu and instruction run.

Answer (score 3):

That quote you put up refers to the perspectve of a complex calculation that uses various variables and constants. The final result will end up where the specification (for instance a high-level language statement) specifies that it should. Take for instance

```
A = ( 3 * B ) + C
```

It is clear that the final result must end up in A, because the statement says so. But most CPU's can't do this calculation without first calculating ( 3 * B ). So where should that value end up? That depends on the type of CPU architecture. In an accumulator architecture the statement would be translated to something like

```
LOAD B   ; accu == B
MULT 3   ; accu == ( B * 3 )
ADD C    ; accu == ( B * 3 ) + C
STORE A  ; A := accu
```

The accumulator (which is not explicitly mentioned in the instructions, because in an accumulator architecture it is the only option) is used to hold the intermidiate (and final!) result of the calculation.

These days acculmulator architectures are out of fashion because the speed difference between CPU and RAM would make them very slow. The dominant architectures are now register-register, where the destination of each calculation can be choosen from a set of registers. Typically these are also load-store architectures, where an operation can either access RAM data, or do a calculation, but not both. For such an architecture the statement could translate to

```
LOAD R0, [ B ]
LOAD R1, 3
MULT R0, R0, R1
LOAD R1, [ C ]
ADD R0, R0, R1
STORE [ A ], R0
```

Answer (score 1):

An accumulator is just combinitorial logic functions as an adder with a register that stores a result. (this is what the wiki is defining as the intermediate register) In most digital logic the value from the accumulator is later stored in a CPU register or if its custom logic the value is used again later.

Because digital logic such as adders contain [multiple gates that have timing dependencies on each other](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=0ahUKEwiVjIyJn9DSAhVU2WMKHU9NByQQFghJMA8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ece.ucsb.edu%2FFaculty%2FJohnson%2FECE152A%2FL4%2520-%2520Propagation%2520Delay%2C%2520Circuit%2520Timing%2520%26%2520Adder%2520Design.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF2XEbHroBex-NelVJ-sji5iF8uiw&sig2=l1SPVeKY3up5IU71xxiHGA&bvm=bv.149397726,d.cGc&cad=rja), it is necessary to clock the logic and place timing constraints on it in the design so you know you have a valid result before the next operation or clock, that's why you use a register or memory to hold the value.

Here is an [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Pipelined_Processors) of a modern CPU pipeline.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer have anything to do with the question?